# NTLM authentication without target info: how is it even possible?

Tags: c++, windows, ntlm

I work on a C++ client application that performs NTLM authentication using Window's API (`InitializeSecurityContext`). Part of the NTLM protocol involves receiving the Domain and Target info from the server in the "type 2" message (or "Challenge" message). This is indicated using the "Negotiate Target Info" flag of the message (BTW: [an excellent resource for NTLM](http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#theNtlmFlags)).

My question concerns a peculiar behavior I noticed using a specific Server I'm authenticating against (though the question is general):

1. In my case, the proxy server (a McAfee WebGateway) against which my client is authenticating, is indicating that the target and domain info are provided -
2. But the server fails to provide this info. this is a bug in the server.
3. What I'm wondering is how *other* applications (like browsers) are capable of completing the handshake, given that they too were not supplied with the target/domain info.

Specifically, I can think of two approaches here: either they somehow complete the missing info themselves. OR they could be re-flagging the Challenge message somehow to correct the server's response. Neither have worked for me - wondering if anyone out there already met this challenge (no pun intended).

Comment: Just a thought, but are there any open source browsers that implement NTLM auth?

Comment: Thank you for this comment - and you're right: Chromium and Firefox are open source and I might be able reverse engineer the relevant code.